# NodeJs Passport performs CORS pre-flight if request comes from VueJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, passport.js, axios

I am writing a NodeJS / Express backend that uses Passport with the Saml-Stategy. I am using an external Identity Provider and VueJs as a frontend.

If I do an API request to the backend from the browser (Chrome + IE) everything works fine. The request goes to the backend, goes to the IdP as GET request and comes back authenticated.

But if I load the VueJs app that does the same request, passport makes a CORS pre-flight (OPTIONS) request that comes back from the IdP as 404, because OPTIONS is not supported. I tried Vue-Resource and Axios, both the same result.

Unfortunately I can not change any settings on the IdP. But why does my passport in the backend treats the requests differently? Any Ideas?
 [image]

I compared the request headers from the API call and VueJs, and I cant find any headers that would cause the pre-flight.

[image]

Repository: https://github.com/tmschbgr/NodePassportExample

Versions:

- Node: 8.9.0
- Express: 4.16.2
- Passport: ^0.4.0
- Passport-saml: ^0.31.0
- Vue: ^2.4.4
- Axios: ^0.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was causing due to a timing issue.

It works with the following logic:

1. Request comes to Backend, check if authenticated
2. If not, go to IdP and come back. If successful redirect to /
3. Serve the static file AFTER the authentication check. That way the app only gets served when the user is authenticated.